# Allocating an array of Derived without new[]: Pointer to Base vtable is bad

Tags: c++, inheritance, dynamic-memory-allocation, vtable

Basically, I have a pure virtual class Base, and a concrete class Derived which inherits from Base. I then allocate a piece of memory and treat it as an array of Derived via a simple cast. Then, I populate the array using =. Finally, I loop through the array, trying to call the virtual method GetIndex that is declared in Base and defined in Derived.

The problem is that I end up getting an access violation exception trying to read the pointer to the vtable for Base (in Visual Studio debugging, this is shown as __vfptr, and it is always 0xbaadf00d).

Following is a simple example of the problem I am encountering:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "windows.h"

struct Base
{
    virtual int GetIndex() const = 0;
};

struct Derived : public Base
{
    int index;

    Derived()
    {
        static int test = 0;
        index = test++;
    }

    int GetIndex() const
    {
        return index;
    }
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    int count = 4;
    // Also fails with malloc
    Derived* pDerived = (Derived*)HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), 0, sizeof(Derived) * count);

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        Derived t;
        pDerived[i] = t;
    }

    // Should print 0 1 2 3
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        Base& lc = pDerived[i];
        printf("%d\n", lc.GetIndex()); // FAIL!
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This behavior only occurs when allocating the memory via HeapAlloc or malloc; if new[] is used, it works fine. (Also, the cstor is called 4 times previously, so the output is 4 5 6 7.)

Comment: For reference, this was solved by replacing:

    Derived t;
    pDerived[i] = t;

with:

    new (&pDerived[i]) Derived();

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you allocate memory without `new` you always need to call the constructor manually with [placement new](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222557/cs-placement-new) and the destructor with `x->~Derived();`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use an allocator besides C++'s default, you should define your own operator new rather than try to remember to call the constructor every time.

```
void *operator new[]( size_t block_size, HANDLE heap ) {
    return HeapAlloc( heap, 0, block_size );
}
```

…

```
Derived *pDerived = new( GetProcessHeap() ) Derived[ count ];
```

Details depend on whether you want it to be the default way of allocating `Derived` and whether it really needs parameters.

You still need to be careful if `free()` can't free the memory you got. Then the default `delete` won't work, and you should either create `Derived::operator delete` or write your own function which calls `object->~Derived()`.

Answer (score 0):

I think inside the first for loop you are creating a object without new. Which means that the context of this object is your for loop. This variable no longer exists when you quit the for loop.